# Prevent wrapping of text within divs, but not without

Tags: html, css

I have a set of tags in an outer div, like so:

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║ ╔═══════╗╔═════╗╔═══╗╔═══════╗╔═══╗
║ ║ tag 1 ║║ t 2 ║║ 3 ║║ tag 4 ║║ 5 ║  ❌
║ ╚═══════╝╚═════╝╚═══╝╚═══════╝╚═══╝
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

I want the tags to wrap like so:

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ ╔═══════╗╔═════╗╔═══╗ ║
║ ║ tag 1 ║║ t 2 ║║ 3 ║ ║  ✅
║ ╚═══════╝╚═════╝╚═══╝ ║
║    ╔═══════╗╔═══╗     ║
║    ║ tag 4 ║║ 5 ║     ║
║    ╚═══════╝╚═══╝     ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

But no matter what I've tried, so far I can only get the overflow like in the first example, or wrapping *within* the inner divs, like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║ ╔═══════╗╔═════╗╔═══╗╔════ ║
║ ║ tag 1 ║║ t 2 ║║ 3 ║║ tag ║
║ ╚═══════╝╚═════╝╚═══╝╚════ ║  ❌
║          ═══╗╔═══╗         ║
║           4 ║║ 5 ║         ║
║          ═══╝╚═══╝         ║
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

Is there anyway to get the desired behavior with just CSS, with the following criteria met?

**Criteria**

- Inner divs never wrap internally (required)
- Outer div hugs content height (required)
- Inner div layout is centered horizontally within outer div (required)
- Outer div hugs content width (preferred)

  - (or, acceptable-but-undesired) Outer div has fixed-width

Comment: Can you please post a pen/jsfiddle? What do you mean by that drawing that inner divs break?

Comment: make the inner element inline-block

Comment: Thank you, @TemaniAfif!  I had`display: inline-block;` on the outer div, but not the inner div, and then got lost down a rabbit-hole of trying to use CSS attributes with "wrap" in the name. Adding it to the inner divs did the trick. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a display of inner div to `display: inline-block` and provide a width for the outer div. Then, you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main{
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.inner{
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: RGBA(200,30,30,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Tag1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Tag2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Tag3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Tag4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Tag5</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for demonstrating how to do a code snippet in GitHub. I'd not encountered that before…or I did, but didn't pay attention.  Second, this doesn't quite do it. If you change the .inner height to `50px` and change "Tag2" to "Tag 2 Longer Name", you'll see that the tag's text gets wrapped. The behavior I was asked to implement was to have "Tag 2 Longer Name" wrap down below "Tag1" if it hit the edge of the outer div. I would have posted more detail to clarify this, but Temani had already solved the problem for me in the comments.